Parallel transport(in terms of $S^2$)
I'm trying to find parallel transport(in terms of unit sphere $S^2$ along the curve b(t)=($\frac{sint}{\sqrt{2}}$, $\frac{sint}{\sqrt{2}}$, cost) of the vector (1,1,0) from the point A(0,0,1) to the point B($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,0).
Firstly, for the points given I concluded that t ranges in [0,$\frac{π}{2} $]. I also used spherical coordinates so that b(t)=($\frac{π}{4}$ ,t) θ=π/4 and φ=t). Then I tried using the appropriate differential equation with Christoffel symbols to find the parallel V(t), but when it comes to transferring vector (1,1,0) in the equation i get stuck.

I think it might be easier if we start by translating to spherical coordinates. We have the inclination angle $\theta = \arccos(z) = t$ and the azimuthal angle $\phi = \arctan(y/x) = \pi/4$ is constant, since $x>0$ for the interval $[0,\pi/2]$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system.
So in spherical coordinates the curve is given by $(t,\pi/4)$ with tangent vector $v=(1,0)$. Let $x$ be the sought after curve, with $x(0)=(0,\pi/4)$. The parallell transport equation says in spherical coordinates:
$$ 0=(\nabla_v x)^i = dx^i/dt + \Gamma^i_{kj} x^kv^j = dx^i/dt + \Gamma^i_{k1}x^k. $$
Focusing on the second $\phi$-component $i=2$, we get the only nonzero Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^2_{21}=-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=-\sin(t)\cos(t).$ The equation you need solve is then
$$ dx^2/dt=sin(t)\cos(t)x^2, \quad x^2(0) = \pi/4. $$
You can also think about what happens to the first component.

What is the metric you used to find Christoffel symbols?

Sorry I should have written that. It is the "round metric", which is induced from the ambient Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Namely, $g = d\theta\wedge d\theta + \sin^2(\theta)d\phi\wedge d\phi$.
